# How to make small addition to inherited gem controller and where to put 'super'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm using devise, and would like to add a `special_method` if a user model is updated successfully. Below is the source code for the registrationsController that I am inheriting from.

I want to add just one line, a `special_method` method as commented.

**class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController**

```
def update
  self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
  prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

  if resource.update_with_password(account_update_params)
    # Where I want to run `special_method` on my updated user
    if is_navigational_format?
      flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
        :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
      set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
    end
    sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
    respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

What's the best way to write this in my controller? Is the code below the most concise way, or is there a way to trim it down even more?

**class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController**

```
def update
  self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
  prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

  if resource.update_with_password(account_update_params)
    resource.special_method
    super
  else
    super
  end
end
```

EDIT: So my sample code above doesn't work because it relies on protected methods in the Devise::RegistrationsController. This in turn relies on another method in a different devise controller. How can I access these methods without overwriting the original controller/helper files?

To clarify,

- My controller has an `update` method which includes an `account_update_params` method.
- Devise::RegistrationsController has a protected `account_update_params` method which includes a `devise_parameter_sanitizer` method
- Devise::Controllers::Helpers has a `devise_parameter_sanitizer` method which creates new instances of Devise::ParameterSanitizer and Devise::BaseSanitizer

Is there an easy way to access these methods, or bypass including them in my code via `super`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path, have you updated your routes file to use your overriding controller?

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Your update method can't call super the way you are using it, super will run the whole method again, not just the section it's placed in. You would do better to replace your update method with a copy of the base one, then insert your new method call (basically, uncomment your comment!)

Devise is designed to be inherited and modified this way, private methods and helpers shouldn't cause you any grief at all so long as you are routing correctly.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's perfect. I already had the route set up as you said, and it turns out the issue I mentioned in the edit to my question is unrelated--I just simply needed to replace `account_update_params` with the `params[:user]` that I would be getting from my view.